# Spring Integration xsl-resource from database

Tags: java, xml, spring, xslt, integration

In Spring Integration, is there any way to load an xsl-resource dynamically, say from a database without it being horribly hacky?

```
<int-xml:xslt-transformer id="tenderXsltTransformer"
                          input-channel="tenderTransformChannel" 
                          output-channel="tenderOutChannel" 
                          xsl-resource="classpath:/META-INF/xsl/submit-info.xsl" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well int-xml:xslt-transformer use under it [XsltPayloadTransformer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/xml/transformer/XsltPayloadTransformer.html) so you can code something around it to do what you need.

Comment: But the short answer, I'm guessing, is there's no way in configuration alone to specify a database resource?

Comment: True, you can't do that from just a configuration. You need to write some code to retrive data from DB and represent it as a Spring `Resource`. Anyway that `Resource` can't be dynamic for the `XsltPayloadTransformer`. It is a heavy object and it would be a bad idea to retrive it for each message. Maybe a set of `<int-xml:xslt-transformer>` and a `<router>` is a good compromise for you? Anyway, there is no built-in resource representation for the DB.